# To perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection

Tags: ldap

I am trying to get user attributes from ldap using user id.
When i connect to server and use this command **conn.result** to check the result then it shows me success.
But when I try to do search operation using command
"**conn.search(base_dn, group_filter, subtree)**" and then again when i check **conn.result** then it shows me error message 
**"To perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection"**
The issue is i have written code in .net and thats passing the same base_dn and group_filters but it works there but not in python.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried (CODE) and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: server = ("LDAPS://uri", get_info=ALL)
conn = connect(server, auto_bind = True)
search = conn.Search(base_dn, search_filter, subtree)

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it's completely illegible. Put it into your question, where it should have been in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

For me helped changing connection port from 389 to 3268

Answer (score -2):

Typically this error implies you are using Microsoft Active Directory and are not performing a Successful Bind to the Directory.

We have [Java Examples for use with LDAP](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/master/)

Comment: I am using ldap3 in python

Comment: The error message *states explicitly* that you have to perform a successful bind, and there is no implication that you are using Microsoft Active Directory or any other specific implementation of LDAP. Link broken.